# Mark a function as data.table-unaware

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like a function I wrote that expects a data frame to work with data tables just as if they were data frames; e.g., I want `d[, j]` to do the same thing whether the argument `d` is a data frame or data table.

I know that `data.table:::cedta` is used in `[.data.table` to detect whether data frame compatibility mode should be on. How do I force it on for a particular function?

Answer (score 3):

Use `setDF` (and `setDT`):

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(x = 1:2, y = 3:4)

foo <- function(d, j) {
  test <- is.data.table(d)
  if (test) setDF(d)
  res <- d[,j]
  if (test) setDT(d) #necessary to avoid changing DT
  res
}

foo(DT, 1)
#[1] 1 2

as.data.frame(DT)[, 1]
#[1] 1 2

DT[, 1]
#   x
#1: 1
#2: 2
```

Comment: Promising, but wouldn't this remove data table-specific metadata such as the key?

Comment: @Kodiologist Yeah, good point, eg `DT = data.table(a = 1, key="a"); key(DT); res <- (function(d) setDF(setDT(d)))(DT); key(DT)` I guess taking a shallow copy is an alternative option. Or just use `[.data.frame` explicitly, of course...`library(data.table); DT = data.table(a = 1:2, key="a"); (function(d) base::\`[.data.frame\`(d, , 1))(DT)`

Comment: @Frank Using `[.data.frame` explicitly is probably worth its own answer. It's the closest to what I asked for yet.

Answer (score 2):

If the only problem is what happens inside `[.data.table`, you can call `[.data.frame` instead:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(a = 1:2, key="a")

# data.table behavior
`[`(DT, , 1)
#    a
# 1: 1
# 2: 2

# data.frame behavior
(function(d) base::`[.data.frame`(d, , 1))(DT)
# [1] 1 2
```

I guess the `base::` prefix probably is not needed. You could also write your function into a non-CEDTA package and load it from there.

Comment: "You could also write your function into a non-CEDTA package and load it from there." — Do you think there's a way to do that inline in an ordinary R script, without making a complete package directory hierarchy and so on? Perhaps using namespaces?

Comment: @Kodiologist Interesting idea. I have never made a package, so it's over my head, though.

Answer (score 1):

Most straightforward way is to differentiate explicitly..

You can detect the class of the argument passed to your function using something like this in your clauses..

```
a <- c(1,2,3) %>% data.table()
"data.table" %in% class(a)
#[1] TRUE
b <- c(1,2,3) %>% data.frame()
"data.table" %in% class(b)
#[1] FALSE
#  Do stuff
```

To avoid writing the logic twice you could apply `as.data.table` to the argument and then you are able to use only one type of syntax.

Comment: While this approach would work, it doesn't seem ideal because one has to write the same logic twice, once for the case when `d` is a data table and once for when it's a data frame.

Comment: I think you could avoid that by explicitly converting the object to data.table, if it is not one already, and then apply the logic only once.

Comment: In that case, see Roland's answer and my comment on it.

Comment: I dont think it would remove metadata, since you are only converting when it is not already a data.table...

Comment: Oh, I misread you; you're suggesting to convert data frames to data tables, not the reverse. Interesting, although not quite what I asked for (since I'm trying to use data-frame syntax with data tables).